# how to instanciate a list with an array of list like in the example?

Tags: c#, windows, list

I have to make two lists in C # . How do the second list ?
The first is well and works , the second already tried as exemplified below but does not work . And I want it to be exactly like or similar without the use of other variables

```
List<String> t = new List<string>()    {"question","anotherQuestion"};
```

then i want another list

and i would like to initialize it like this.

```
List<String[]> t = new List<string[]>()  
{
   ("rightawnser","wrongAwnser"),  //1st question
   ("rightawnser","wrongAwnser"),  //2nd question

};
```

Comment: not seem to be exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but you have to create an array for each list entry:

```
List<string[]> t = new List<string[]>()  
{
   new[] { "rightawnser","wrongAwnser" },  //1st question
   new[] { "rightawnser","wrongAwnser" },  //2nd question
};
```

Comment: thank you. worked just fine

Comment: @HelderPereira No problem. Please consider accepting the answer to help others.

Comment: i would love to, but dont i dont have reputation enough yet

Comment: @HelderPereira If you can ask questions, you can accept answers. Not really important though I guess.

Comment: sorry. you were right. didn't know. i dont have permitions yet is to rate.